# Should I wait before upvoting the first answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

[I asked a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46964/what-to-do-with-a-cluster-of-old-computers-running-ubuntu) regarding computer clusters. The question was apt for the community wiki, and was made into one. The first response that it received was good and I upvoted it. However since then, the question has not received any further answers.

Should I have waited before upvoting so that it stayed a bit longer in the unanswered section.

Or is offering a bounty the only way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it matters much. If lots of people are interested in a question, it's going to get answers what ever the voting on the previous answers looks like.

If you want to get more and better answers, edit your question and make it better. Read [our FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) as well, it will tell you what sort of question this community really likes, and what sort it doesn't like so much.

This will all be more valuable than voting tactics.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo The question only has like 71 views, it might be a good investment just tweeting/facebooking the question all over to get more ideas.